# blocking new processes system

Tags: kill, ps, watch-command

is there a way to kill all new processes that appear in `watch -n 0 ps -A -o cmd -o pid` by new processes i mean everything after the PC start by 30 seconds, every command which did not run in that 30 second to be considered as new.
want i want is to make **kill -STOP (ID)** for all new processes.
and *why would i want to do that?* >because i want to make a system that block all new processes and send alert to the user if he/she wants to resume the process or not.
i hope if someone help me,
thanks,

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Wouldn't the alert be a new process?

Comment: somehow i am talking about a HIDS  it is like comodo firewall HIDS in windows but i want to make it in ubuntu and observe the processes not the files unlike comodo